# SQL query not returning same value as its subqueries results would suggest

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have written a query that is supposed to find which pupils have logged into the app in the current week. my SQLite query looks like this:

```
public static final String WHOLE_QUERY = "SELECT " + DBHelperTest.USER_ID
            + " , " + DBHelperTest.FNAME + " , " + DBHelperTest.SNAME
            + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_CHILD + " WHERE "
            + DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " = (SELECT " + DBHelperTest.USER_ID
            + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_SESSION_DATA + " WHERE "
            + DBHelperTest.WEEK_OF_YEAR_SIGNED_IN + " = " + theWeek() + " AND "
            + DBHelperTest.YEAR_SIGNED_IN + " = " + theYear() + ") " + " AND "
            + DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " = (" + "SELECT "
            + DBHelperTest.Child_USER_ID + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_CLASS
            + " WHERE " + DBHelperTest.Teacher_USER_ID + " = (SELECT "
            + DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_SESSION_DATA
            + " WHERE " + DBHelperTest.SESSION_ID + " = ( SELECT MAX("
            + DBHelperTest.SESSION_ID + ") FROM "
            + DBHelperTest.TABLE_SESSION_DATA + ")))";
```

It returns nothing. However If I split it into two queries...

firstly this query shows all the users logged in this week:

```
public static final String LOGGED_IN_THIS_WEEK_QUERY = "SELECT "
            + DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " , " + DBHelperTest.FNAME + " , "
            + DBHelperTest.SNAME + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_CHILD
            + " WHERE " + DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " = (SELECT "
            + DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_SESSION_DATA
            + " WHERE " + DBHelperTest.WEEK_OF_YEAR_SIGNED_IN + " = "
            + theWeek() + " AND " + DBHelperTest.YEAR_SIGNED_IN + " = "
            + theYear() + ") ";
```

this query outputs the user with userId "Jasm".

secondly this query shows all the users associated with the given teacher:

```
   public static final String CHILD_WITH_SAME_TEACHER_QUERY = "SELECT "
                + DBHelperTest.Child_USER_ID + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_CLASS
                + " WHERE " + DBHelperTest.Teacher_USER_ID + " = (SELECT "
                + DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " FROM " + DBHelperTest.TABLE_SESSION_DATA
                + " WHERE " + DBHelperTest.SESSION_ID + " = ( SELECT MAX("
                + DBHelperTest.SESSION_ID + ") FROM "
                + DBHelperTest.TABLE_SESSION_DATA + "))";
```

this query outputs users with userId's "Jasm" and "thup".

why does my original query not output the details of "Jasm" as this user meets both criteria?

please see below for a more easily readable version:

whole query:

```
SELECT USER_ID ,  FNAME , SNAME 
FROM TABLE_CHILD
WHERE USER_ID = 
(
SELECT USER_ID  
FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA
WHERE WEEK_OF_YEAR_SIGNED_IN = theWeek()  
AND YEAR_SIGNED_IN = theYear()
) 
AND USER_ID = 
(
SELECT Child_USER_ID 
FROM TABLE_CLASS
WHERE Teacher_USER_ID = 
(
SELECT USER_ID 
FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA
WHERE SESSION_ID = 
( 
SELECT MAX(SESSION_ID) 
FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA)))
```

first half

```
SELECT USER_ID ,  FNAME , SNAME 
FROM TABLE_CHILD
WHERE USER_ID = 
(
SELECT USER_ID  
FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA
WHERE WEEK_OF_YEAR_SIGNED_IN = theWeek()  
AND YEAR_SIGNED_IN = theYear()
)
```

second half

```
SELECT Child_USER_ID 
FROM TABLE_CLASS
WHERE Teacher_USER_ID = 
(
SELECT USER_ID 
FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA
WHERE SESSION_ID = 
( 
SELECT MAX(SESSION_ID) 
FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA))
```

Comment: Your question would be much more understandable if you put in the string values *after* substitution, rather than the code for generating the strings.  Your code is very, very difficult to read.

Comment: thanks for your comment, the reason I did it like this is to ensure that any error in my code is accurately documented. i will however take this comment on board and additionally include the code in a more readable format. i take it that you would like something more like:
SELECT userId, fName, sName
FROM table_child ..?

Comment: You should include the code that the database is actually running.  Your problem appears to be with the results of a SQL query.  That is what you should focus on.  How that query is written is rather irrelevant to answering your question.

Comment: i have updated my question and i hope that it is now of an acceptable standard. thanks again for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "IN" operator instead of "=" to select multiple results instead of just one.

In your code:

```
+ DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " IN (SELECT " + DBHelperTest.USER_ID
...
+ DBHelperTest.USER_ID + " IN (" + "SELECT "
```

Comment: as you can probably tell i'm new to this so thank you so much for teaching me something new!!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm interesting.
I’ve written this below as nicely formatted SQL (and I’ve changed the date functions to the corresponding T-SQL functions that I am more familiar with).

I don’t have the underlying data to allow me to play with this query so I can only look at the code.

This looks like a series of self-contained (non-correlated) sub-queries and I guess at first glance should work.

The deepest subquery will return either NULL or a single value.
All the other subqueries use “=” and the equivalence operator won’t work with more than one value, although looking at the subqueries (without having the data) perhaps more than one value in the result set is possible?
Perhaps you are just not getting back a meaningful  error message from SQLite for that?

Is this where it’s going wrong perhaps? More than value being returned somewhere?
Might this might become more apparent if you used “IN” as opposed to “=” ?

If not, could you post some sample data that allows the issue to be duplicated perhaps?

```
SELECT USER_ID, FNAME .SNAME
FROM TABLE_CHILD
WHERE USER_ID =
    (
        SELECT USER_ID
        FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA
        WHERE WEEK_OF_YEAR_SIGNED_IN  = datepart(week,getdate())
        AND
        YEAR_SIGNED_IN  =  datepart(year,getdate()) 
        AND
        USER_ID =
             (
                SELECT Child_USER_ID
                FROM TABLE_CLASS
                WHERE Teacher_USER_ID =
                        (
                            SELECT USER_ID
                            FROM
                            TABLE_SESSION_DATA
                            WHERE SESSION_ID = 
                                (
                                    SELECT MAX(SESSION_ID)
                                    FROM TABLE_SESSION_DATA
                                )
                         )
              )
    )
```

Comment: Andy you are a legend, thank you for putting so much effort into your answer. if i had enough reputation i'd give you an upvote!

i've accepted the first answer already, the user also pointed out that i could get multiple results so i needed to use an IN clause instead of " = ". i've researched this now and will be able to use it in future, without bothering the experts!

Comment: also thanks for the top tips with regard to the T-SQL.